# rails select uniq and most recent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of objects that I'd like to select the most recent of each object from. The array is ordered by creation date.

Each object has a unique id, and a non-unique foreign key (which is below). They also have datestamps as well.

For example :

[1, 2, 1, ***3***, ***1***, 2, 4, ***4***, ***2***]

How do I only select the ones in bold? ***(3,1,4,2)***.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array by creation date descending, that way if you run a `uniq` on the array, it will return the first of each item.

For example:

```
arr.sort_by { |o| o[:date] }.reverse!.uniq { |o| o[:id] }
```